# RAM upgrade, laptop won't boot after restart. Works on initial boot

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios, hp-elitebook

I'm getting a weird issue with a RAM upgrade. I'm trying to upgrade to 32GB (2x16GB, previously 2x8).

With 2x16 combo, the first boot works well. I get a BIOS notification that RAM settings have changed. I can boot into Ubuntu and see that I have 32GB. 
After a restart, the computer won't boot anymore. Motherboard starts beeping and I have a black screen (so unable to access bios).

The beeps hint at a memory issue: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Boot-and-Lockup/No-screen-on-startup-3-long-beeps-2-short-beeps/td-p/6979452
The tricks hinted in the hp forum aren't helping.

**What I've tried**

- 8 + 16 combo has no trouble at all and everything works perfectly
- Both 16GB RAM sticks are working properly (tested with 8+16 combo)
- Updated BIOS
- Tested adding RAM sticks one by one.
  With only one new memory stick inserted the computer has the same issue as 2 new sticks inserted. Looks like everything is OK only if the original stick is inserted.

Laptop: HP Elitebook 850 G5 (Board 83B2, should support 32GB RAM)
RAM (2): [HyperX Impact 16GB 2400MHz DDR4 CL14 260-Pin SODIMM Laptop Memory
HX424S14IB16](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01BNJL8K2)

---

Edit (more info):

[Motherboard's supported memory config](https://support.hp.com/ee-en/document/c05903028)

[image]

CPUZ with both new RAM sticks added (first boot)

[image]

Comment: Could be that you have a problem with your mobo accepting 32GB of RAM in dual channel. If you can enter the BIOS, make sure dual channel is enabled, and then go back to the HP website to make sure that your PC supports that amount of RAM in dual channel, not single.

Comment: @Didier I updated the initial post with the supported memory config. Dual-channel is supported. As far as I read, there's no manual configuration to enable dual channel in bios (also couldn't find it).

- I can't get into bios with 2 new sticks added; I tested some more and the same issue happens if only 1 new stick is added (I can only boot the first time). It looks like the new stick only works if it's side-by-side with one of the original sticks.

Comment: Added CPUZ screenshot with both new RAM sticks inside. Also shows that it's running in dual channel.

Comment: One difference between old and new ram sticks seems to be that old ram is "Rank: 1", but new is "Rank: 2". As much as google tells me (I don't know much about this "Rank" property), this shouldn't be an issue in this case (looks like motherboard supports rank 2 ram as well).

Comment: Did you reset the BIOS to default as indicated in one of the posts, by pressing the Windows and B keys simultaneously while keeping your finger on the Power button for a few seconds?

Comment: @Didier yes, I tried that (and other methods in the post)

Comment: How did you fix it? I have same problem.